# Select drop-down not rendering correctly when populated with Update

Tags: javascript, jsp, prototype

I have a drop-down menu declared in a JSP page like so:

```
<div id = "tagRevisions" name = "tagRevisions" width="100" style="position:absolute; bottom:2px; right:2px;">
<select id="tagRevisionsSelect" name="tagRevisionsSelect" onChange="header.loadTag('<%= strTagID %>', '<%= lastApprovedRequestId %>', this.value);">

       <% 
        // Some code here
       %>
</select>
</div>
```

Initially it is empty. I populate it via JavaScript and Prototype like this:

```
rebuildRequestsDropDown : function()
{
    jsonrpc.tagGridUtils.buildRequestsDropDownHTML(function(result, exception)
        {
            if (exception)
            {
                alert("There was an error " + exception.toString());
            }
            else
            {                   
                // Set the innerHTML of the Requests drop-down to the result
                // returned by the function above.
                if (result != null && result.trim() != "")
                {
                    $("tagRevisionsSelect").update(result);
                }
            }
        }.bind(this),

        $("cacheId").value
    );
}
```

So what's happening is the drop-down gets populated but it gets rendered incorrectly on the page. It looks like this:

[image]

If I minimize and then maximize the window or hit a Tab on the page then it looks fine:

[image]

Why is that?

ps: here is the HTML output:

[image]

Comment: Please show the actual HTML output, not your server-side Java code.

Comment: <div id = "tagRevisions" name = "tagRevisions" width="100" style="position:absolute; bottom:2px; right:2px;">
 <select id="tagRevisionsSelect" name="tagRevisionsSelect" onChange="header.loadTag('EES_AECC01XLGCR14_EES', '4', this.value);">
  
           
 </select>
</div>

Comment: Is this what you meant by HTML output?

Comment: Look at the original message above. I added the HTML output from IE Developer Tools.

Answer (score 0):

try to defined the styles for your selectbox. I mean at least it's width.